# Does a video show Michael Brown robbing a store in Ferguson the day he was shot?

Tags: united-states, criminology

The [Inquisitr](http://www.inquisitr.com/1413862/michael-brown-robbery-conspiracy-theory/) reports that there is a conspiracy theory regarding the alleged robbery by shooting victim [Michael Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Michael_Brown).

The theory claims that the video, claimed by the police to prove Brown robbed a store, is not from August 2014as claimed, but from June. Enlarged stills of the video are used to demonstrate this

Is the video from August 9th as the police claim? Does it actually show Michael Brown robbing a store?

Answer (score 5):

The still shots of single video frames, presented in the *Inquisitr* article look ambiguous or incorrect. The month digit is unclear. It doesn't look like an eight and there is no other eight for comparison. Even the sixes (6) look different from each other in a given frame! The "six oddity" may be an optical illusion due to different hues of background imagery.

However, in context of the actual 1 min 30 sec video clip, *[CBS News surveillance video](http://www.cbsnews.com/videos/ferguson-police-release-surveillance-video-related-to-michael-brown-shooting/)*, the numbering `8 09` is very visible throughout the footage. The numbering is not unclear.

The scene is clearly a confrontation inside a store, although it is not entirely obvious what the altercation is about. Michael Brown shoves past, then turns on and shoves again, hard, a slight, middle-aged man who seems to be a worker at the store, trying to bar the door with his arm outstretched.